How to implement MC dropout in keras?
I'm very new to ML and especially more sophisticated techniques like dropout. I have a simple 1D CNN (regression problem), and I would like to capture uncertainties in the predictions for each output pixel. I would like to take advantage of MC dropout for this. This is the model where I've now added a dropout layer after each convolutional layer (not present earlier):
# Define the model architecture
model = keras.Sequential()

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, start_from_epoch=20, min_delta=0.00001, 
                                            verbose=True, restore_best_weights=True)

# Convolutional layers
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=6, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_size,1), name='conv1d_1'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, name='max_pooling1d_1'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=48, kernel_size=6, activation='relu', name='conv1d_3'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, name='max_pooling1d_3'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=6, activation='relu', name='conv1d_4'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, name='max_pooling1d_4'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

# Flatten the output for dense layers
model.add(layers.Flatten(name='flatten_1'))

# Dense layers
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_2'))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='dense_3'))

# Output layer
model.add(layers.Dense(output_size, activation='linear', name='dense_4'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mean_absolute_percentage_error'])

To train the model and quantify uncertainties:
# Train (shape of train and test data are (N_samples, 500))
history = model.fit(train_data[..., np.newaxis], train_truth, batch_size=32, epochs=50, validation_data=(val_data[..., np.newaxis], val_truth), callbacks=[callback])

# Get predictions and uncertainties (only checking for first 10 samples)
y = np.stack([model(test_data[:10, ..., np.newaxis], training=True) for sample in range(100)])
mu = np.mean(y, axis=0)
sigma = np.std(y, axis=0)

However, sigma is basically zero for each prediction at each pixel, even though the error on the testing set predictions are over 10%. I also noticed that if I comment out the dropout layers and re-train and re-evaluate, the resulting sigma values are also zero (but I think this would be expected in this case).
I would think that including the dropout layers should result in non-negligible uncertainties, especially since the performance is fairly poor already! What am I doing wrong?
